# FileNotFoundError in iterating over files under a directory

Tags: python, pandas, directory, pathlib

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

FILES = os.listdir("/CADEC/original")

for file in FILES:
    if file.startswith("ARTHROTEC."):
        print(file)
```

```
ARTHROTEC.1.ann
ARTHROTEC.10.ann
ARTHROTEC.100.ann
ARTHROTEC.101.ann
ARTHROTEC.102.ann
ARTHROTEC.103.ann
ARTHROTEC.104.ann
ARTHROTEC.105.ann
ARTHROTEC.106.ann
ARTHROTEC.107.ann
ARTHROTEC.108.ann
ARTHROTEC.109.ann
ARTHROTEC.11.ann
ARTHROTEC.110.ann
ARTHROTEC.111.ann
ARTHROTEC.112.ann
ARTHROTEC.113.ann
ARTHROTEC.114.ann
ARTHROTEC.115.ann
...
```

I want to extract data from all the files starting with certain letters under a directory. As shown above, when I iterate over the directory and print every file name that fits, I get a column of file names (strings). Meanwhile, `data = pd.read_csv("/CADEC/original/ARTHROTEC.1.ann", sep='\t', header=None)` works perfectly well. However, running the following code would just return error. Why is the file not found? What should I do to fix this?

```py
for file in FILES:
    if file.startswith("ARTHROTEC."):
        data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None)
```

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File ARTHROTEC.1.ann does not exist: 'ARTHROTEC.1.ann'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) only returns the file names in the directory, it does not return the path, and `pandas` needs the path (or relative path) to the file, unless the file is in the same directory as the code.
- You will be better off to learn the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, which treats paths as objects with methods, instead of strings.

  - [`.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) - produces a `Generator` of objects matching the pattern
  - [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)
- `pathlib` may take some getting used to, but all the methods for extracting specific parts of the path, like [`.suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix) for the file extension, or [`.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) for the file name, make it worthwhile.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# create the path object and get the files with .glob
files = Path('/CADEC/original').glob('ARTHROTEC*.ann')

# create a list of dataframes, 1 dataframe for each file
df_list = [pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None) for file in files]

# alternatively, create a dict of dataframes with the filename as the key
df_dict = {file.stem: pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None) for file in files}
```

#### Example

```py
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
import os
  ...: from pathlib import Path
  ...: os.listdir('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files')
Out[2]: 
['.ipynb_checkpoints',
 '03900169.txt',
 '142233.0.txt',
 '153431.2.txt',
 '17371271.txt',
 '274301.5.txt',
 '42010316.txt',
 '429237.7.txt',
 '570651.4.txt',
 '65500027.txt',
 '688599.3.txt',
 '740103.5.txt',
 '742537.6.txt',
 '87505504.txt',
 '90950222.txt',
 't1.txt',
 't2.txt',
 't3.txt']

list(Path('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files').glob('*'))
Out[3]: 
[WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/.ipynb_checkpoints'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/03900169.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/142233.0.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/153431.2.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/17371271.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/274301.5.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/42010316.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/429237.7.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/570651.4.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/65500027.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/688599.3.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/740103.5.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/742537.6.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/87505504.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/90950222.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/t1.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/t2.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/t3.txt')]
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect! Thank you!